# Fiction / Theory: Produce gas version of solid elements

Tags: planets, space, weapons

I am creating a sci-fi like game. I just want to ask if there is a theory how to produce gas version of solid elements in our periodic table. One of the notable element will be Silver and Copper.

if none, can you give some fiction like process to produce those elements in gas version.

The setting of the world is highly advance. You can refer to "Starwars".

**EDIT:**

As @jdunlop suggested to give some function or usage of the gas versions. One of the usage i am thinking is an electric missile. It is like a cheap/another version of EMP. I also want to clarify that i will be needing gas version of these elements **standard temperature and pressure**.

First, let's assume of the area of explosion is a vacuum(Space). I was informed the vacuum space is not a very good conductor.
Using normal explosive missile can produce significant amount of heat,light and impact that can be detected via some instrument in this world. To avoid being seen electric missile is invented. Voila!!

The electric missile have 3 phase.

1. "Silver Gas Release" - We all know that silver is a very good conductor. Once hit, the silver gas will be release.
2. "Capacitor Release" - Let's also assume that a very small capacitor inside the missile can store a large amount of electricity. In this phase the capacitor will release all stored electricity to the silver gas.
3. "EMP like" - Like i have said, It is like a small EMP. This will fry common boards in the target and disable lots of components.

Comment: Uhm, heat them up?  Silver vaporizes at about 1950 degrees Celsius, and Copper vaporizes at around 2595 degrees Celsius. Congrats, you now have gaseous Silver and Copper.

Comment: Please remove the hard-science tag as it is inappropriate.Also, for reference, metallic silver is a good conductor; gaseous silver need not be. It depends on the distance between the silver atoms. Consider any ionised gas for conduction in gaseous phase at stp (note, space is **not** stp). Passing charge through a gaseous medium is not the best way to generate emp. A high amplitude spike of radiation is far more efficient.Consider discharging your capacitor through an antenna instead. You could also focus the pulse that way

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you're worried about detection, an EMP is not your friend.  By definition, they produce an enormous spike of electromagnetic radiation, detectable from at least as far in a vacuum as the light of a conventional explosion.  (Also, in space, you're far better off with something nuclear, both for EMPs and explosions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have *Star Wars*-like tech, perhaps consider a container made of ray-shields, which *Revenge of the Sith* implies can contain atmosphere, and which *A New Hope* implies can block whatever blaster beams are (lasers make far more sense than plasma, but either carries comparable amounts of energy to your metal vapor).

You basically now have a force-field that is permeable to solids, but not hot gas. Trap your super-heated gas in such a container.

If you need gaseous metals at close to room temperature, which a person could plausibly blunder into, that's much harder. It would be easier to make a particulate suspension / colloid (think smoke). Sustaining clouds like that could be challenging (think about how long sky-writing lasts), but clever application of climate control could expand your options (fans, pressurization, humidity, temperature, the exact makeup of the surrounding gas, etc).

Re: ray-shield-box, *A New Hope* puts one of these over a thermal exhaust port, and you need your gas to stay hot. Perhaps it's a light-skillet wrapped in ray-shields?

Answer (score 3):

Posting the correct comment by [Gryphon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159752/fiction-theory-produce-gas-version-of-solid-elements#comment500963_159752) as an answer:

## Heat them up

All elements have a temperature and pressure at which they will become a gas.

[This table covers the boiling points of all elements on the periodic table.](https://periodictable.com/Properties/A/BoilingPoint.html)

If you want some sort of gas-equivalent at [standard temperature and pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure), that's an entirely different question, and one you should spell out explicitly in your posted question.  (If that's what you do want, the answer is "no, they can't be a gas, but you might be able to come up with a functional equivalent if you explain what you want the pseudo-gas to *do*."

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I updated the question with some usage of the gas versions of the elements. I also want to clarify that i will be needing gas version of these elements at standard temperature and pressure.

Comment: You want silver and copper to be a gas at standard temperature and pressure? Then what you want is **magic** because your only solution is to throw science out the window.

Answer (score -1):

Like others have stated:

## Just heat 'em up.

All elements can become a gas at specific temperatures and pressures.

> i will be needing gas version of these elements **standard temperature and pressure**.

You want silver and copper to be a gas at standard temperature and pressure?
In that case, what you want is:

## Magic!

Because your only solution is to throw science out the window.

---

## Enter handwavium

Perhaps an assortment of molecule-sized dust particles of these elements can be sprayed in the form of aerosols. Although this isn't quite what you are looking for, it is the best I've come up with.